# index was outside the bounds of the array oracle connection visual studio

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I am still very new at .net development and working with database. I having an issue making a connection string for my MVC application. I was hoping to use entity framework. When I go to make a new ado.net connection using a managed oracle driver I get a error "Index was outside the bounds of the array". Please keep in mind this is actually in the wizard that makes the connection string not in the actually code in the web data file. It should also be mentioned im not using ez connect , Im making the connection from a tns names file. If anyone could tell me why this is happening I would be very grateful as I have to had googled a million different queries on it. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How about you try and connect without using a tns and see if that works. That will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: I would but I am not privy to the connection information needed for that connection type such as port number etc. The DB I am currently able to use is a oracle test environment with copies of tables the are used for day to day operation.